# Add multiple attachments to mail using AppleScript

Tags: finder, applescript, mail.app

I am trying to write an AppleScript file that sends email with multiple attachments from the current Finder selection.

The one I am currently using is working when one item is selected, but not working when two or more items are selected.

Here's my code.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to selection as alias
    set fileName to name of theFile
    set newRefFile to POSIX path of theFile
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
--extract customer name to CnameNFD
set CnameNFD to first text item of fileName
-- prevent broken korean letter
set Cname to ¬
    do shell script "echo " & (CnameNFD as text) & "|iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8"
-- extract date taken using exiftool 
set cDate to ¬
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -d \"%Y-%m-%d\" -DateTimeOriginal " & (newRefFile) & ""
-- extract latter
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
set cDate to last text item of cDate
-- resetting delimiters 
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
--make subject to "Hi + customername"
set theSubject to "Hi" & "[" & Cname & "]"
set theBody to "attachment:  " & fileName & "
date taken: " & cDate & "
BODY contents"
set {text returned:theAddress} to display dialog "write email address" default answer "example@example.com" buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} default button 2
if button returned of result = "Okay" then
    set theAttachment to theFile
    set theAccount to "account"
    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {sender:theAccount, subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}
        set color of words of theNewMessage to {0, 0, 0}
        set color of characters of theNewMessage to {0, 0, 0}
        tell theNewMessage
            set visibile to true
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
            
            try
                make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after the last word of the last paragraph
                set message_attachment to 0
            on error errmess -- oops
                log errmess -- log the error
                set message_attachment to 1
            end try
            log "message_attachment = " & message_attachment
            delay 3
            send
        end tell
    end tell
else
    if button returned of result = "Cancel" then
        display alert "User canceled the job"
    end if
end if
```

I think I need to use the `repeat` function, but I am totally lost...

If I add multiple files, the subject part "Cname" should be one or more. Also, Body contents "fileName" should be one or more. Of course, the current attachment, too..

Where should I begin?

Comment: @user3439894 I've deleted post on stackoverflow. I thought I've done it already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will attach multiple files:

```applescript
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    set theAttachmentList to ¬
        selection as alias list

tell application "Mail"
    
    set theMessage to ¬
        make new outgoing message with properties ¬
            {visible:true, subject:"", content:""}
    
    tell theMessage to ¬
        make new to recipient at end of ¬
            to recipients with properties ¬
            {name:"John Doe", address:"johndoe@domain.com"}
    
    tell content of theMessage
        repeat with thisItem in theAttachmentList
            make new attachment with properties ¬
                {file name:thisItem} at after last paragraph
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    -- send theMessage
    
end tell
```